# Can i use both bindValue and bindParam on a single prepared statement?

Tags: pdo, prepared-statement, bindparam, bindvalue

```
$nome = 'nome';
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT `nome`, `mov`, `gen` FROM table WHERE gen LIKE :gen AND nome = :nome");
$stmt->bindValue(':gen', '%'.$gen.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->bindParam(':nome', $nome, PDO::PARAM_STR);     
$stmt->execute();
```

As you can see, i'm using `bindValue` to bind the value on the operator `LIKE`, because `bindParam` don't allow the use of strings.

I tested here, and i saw none errors, and i also don't found anything on google about using both `bindValue` and `bindParam` on a single prepared statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the SQL statement there is no difference between `bindValue()` and `bindParam()`. The only difference is how--or rather, when--PHP reads the input variables. So you can use both together, although that may cause hard-to-find issues (regarding the result of the SQL operation) later.

So it's best to avoid confusion and stick to `bindValue()` unless you need the special behaviour of `bindParam()`.